# Why should I use anonymous classes in Android instead of class redefinition?

Tags: android, inner-classes, anonymous-class

I'm new in Android dev. I read some books about it. And all authors strongly recommend to use anonymous classes instead of class redefinition.

They say that

```
TextView txtTitle;
...
txtTitle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

   }
});
```

better than

```
   txtTitle.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(position));
   ...

private class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener{
...
}
```

Can anybody explain me why?

Ofc, if I will use redefinition class for many different object this will be the problem for modification.

But if I use my own class only for specific object, so logic of my class will not strongly change, can I use it? Or should I use anonymous class?

Comment: No reason in particular, except that it avoids multiplying classes, and the scope of the anonymous class gives you access to the content of the including class.

Comment: But my MyOnClickListener has access to all variables too =/

Comment: @njzk2 quite the contrary, when you use new OnClickListener you de facto create a new class, try to do it 5 times in some class and see 5 inner classes in the comipler out folder

Comment: @pskink : my formulation is incorrect. I mean that it avoids multiplying java files, which can be bad for organisation, in particular if they are very specialized. Of course, when applicable, I'm all for factorization.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anonymous class will have access to the final outer variables, so it might be more convienient to use this. For instance:

```
 final String x = "123";
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                 // You can acces "x" here.
        }
 });
```

In addition, it's the question of the coding style. Using anonymous can lead to the code which is more verbose but, at the same time, a little bit easier to follow.

Also, non-anonymous class can be instantiated in multiple places.

Comment: But in this example i can send x to my class in constructor.
private class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener{
...
public MyOnClickListener(Strin x){}
}

But ok, i understand that it's question of the coding style, Tnx (:

Comment: @Suvitruf - yes, you can, but then you'll need a private class member to hold it an use it in `onClick()`. It's just not that convienient.

Comment: @Suvitruf - what do you mean? - it is final

Comment: yeh. But what should I do if i need to use not final variable?

Comment: @Suvitruf - unfortunately, you can't. Are you sure you can't just make it final?

Comment: or you can make it an instance member.

Comment: What is the correct way to access the `Context` of my Class in this case? Say I want to create a `Toast` where I need to add the Context of my Class. In the Anonymous class I can not access it.

Comment: @AdrianJandl - you can just use `MyActivity.this` to access `this` of the outer class - assuming your outer class is called `MyActivity`.

Answer (score 3):

why not to implement OnClickListener in your Activity class?

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

Comment: I need it in my Adapter: class public class WorkshopListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{...}
to hang listener on List items

Comment: so let WorkshopListAdapter implements OnClickListener

Comment: but if I want, for example, use onClickListener only on 1 element inside ListItem. Is it correct to use listener on Adapter in this situation?

Comment: Than onClickListener on Adapter will listen all events on List items. Hmmm, I thought it is redundant.